# Restrict postqueue access to admin user

Tags: linux, security, postfix, gentoo

I'm running `postfix` on Gentoo as mailer daemon. During investigation of some queue pileup I found that `/usr/sbin/postqueue` is executable by all users on the system, it happily outputs the current mail queue (with `-q`) for all users.

It looks like this is more or less by design: `postdrop` and `postqueue` are `set-gid` binaries with group `postdrop`.

```
-rwx--s--x  1 root postdrop  15K Apr 10 23:49 postdrop
-rwx--s--x  1 root postdrop  15K Apr 10 23:49 postqueue
```

They are also executable by `other`, something `postfix` seems to require (output of `postfix check`):

```
postfix/postfix-script: warning: not set-gid or not owner+group+world executable: /usr/sbin/postqueue
```

I'm probably missing something of the inner workings, but as far as I see normal users shouldn't have access to the queue, especially since in this configuration all addresses and domains are set virtual (via a database). If a user would poll `postqueue` regularly he could assemble a list of `<from>,<to>` address pairs (`postcat` is restricted, users cannot access the contents of the mail).

`exim` has a configuration option named `queue_list_requires_admin`, but I cannot find something like this for postfix. Is it possible to restrict queue access with postfix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Postfix doesn't use unix permission feature to limit access to `postqueue`. Instead it uses parameters like ' authorized_mailq_users'

> **authorized_mailq_users (static:anyone)**
>
> List of users who are authorized to view the queue.

So,  if you want to limit to particular user, for example: root, you can use

```
authorized_mailq_users = static:root
```

For further info, see `man 1 postqueue`

Comment: Super-user and `$mail_owner` (in this case `postfix`) are always included according to [the documentation](http://postfix.cs.utah.edu/postconf.5.html#authorized_mailq_users), so an empty value (`authorized_mailq_users = `) was exactly what I was looking for.