# CRITICAL: Error code 69 returned from /usr/bin/mailq while using check_mailq plugin

Tags: postfix, icinga2

While running check_mailq with root user output is as expected but with icinga user it is giving below error:

```
[root@servername ~]# /icinga/plugins/libexec/check_mailq  -w 1 -c 2
postqueue: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
WARNING: postfix mailq is 1 (threshold w = 1)|unsent=1;1;2;0

[root@servername ~]# su - icinga
[icinga@servername ~]$ /icinga/plugins/libexec/check_mailq  -w 1 -c 2
postqueue: fatal: Queue report unavailable - mail system is down
CRITICAL: Error code 69 returned from /usr/bin/mailq
```

I added icinga user to all below groups

```
[icinga@servername~]$ groups
icinga root mail smmsp postfix postdrop cgred icinga_cmd
```

And changed group permission (+rx) for directory and sub-directories under /var/spool/postfix/, /var/spool/clientmqueue/ , /var/spool/mqueue/, /var/spool/snmptt/ & /var/spool/mail/

```
]#ll /var/spool/postfix/
drwxr-x---.  2 postfix root     20480 Jul 17 11:00 active
drwxr-x---.  2 postfix root      4096 Jul 17 11:00 bounce
drwxr-x---.  2 postfix root      4096 Oct 31  2016 corrupt
drwxr-x---. 18 postfix root      4096 Oct 31  2016 defer
drwxr-x---. 18 postfix root      4096 Oct 31  2016 deferred
drwxr-x---.  2 postfix root      4096 Oct 31  2016 flush
drwxr-x---.  2 postfix root      4096 Oct 31  2016 hold
drwxr-x---.  2 postfix root      4096 Jul 17 11:00 incoming
drwxrwx---.  2 postfix postdrop 20480 Jul 17 11:06 maildrop
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root    root      4096 Jul 17 11:05 pid
drwxr-x---.  2 postfix root      4096 Jul 17 06:22 private
drwxr-x---.  2 postfix postdrop  4096 Jul 17 06:22 public
drwxr-x---.  2 postfix root      4096 Oct 31  2016 saved
drwxr-x---.  2 postfix root      4096 Oct 31  2016 trace

]#ls -ld /var/spool/clientmqueue/
drwxrwx---. 2 smmsp smmsp 5398528 Aug 21  2017 /var/spool/clientmqueue/

]#ls -ld /var/spool/mqueue/
drwxr-x---. 2 root mail 4096 May 27  2016 /var/spool/mqueue/

]#ls -ld /var/spool/snmptt/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 snmptt snmptt 995328 Jul 17 11:21 /var/spool/snmptt/

]# ls -ld /var/spool/mail/
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root mail 4096 Jul 17 11:00 /var/spool/mail/
```

When I run `mailq` command with root user it shows mails in queue but with icinga user it just says `postqueue: fatal: Queue report unavailable`

Please help me to understand if i'm missing anything, why mailq is not giving correct output with icinga user.

> Note: I don't want to use sudo.

Comment: You missed "Mail system is down"

Comment: yeah that is intentional, postfix is stopped. Can you please help me to understand why icinga user is not able to view the mail queue like root.

Comment: Did you check https://serverfault.com/questions/682025/restrict-postqueue-access-to-admin-user ?